# Использовать один класс для сохранения разных таблиц в БД

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Есть класс `Uslugi`, код ниже описывает его начало

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "uslugi_poliklinika")
public class Uslugi {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
    
    ***
}
```

Необходимо этот класс использовать для сохранения в несколько разных таблиц БД. Т.е. у другого класса будет `@Table(name = "uslugi_uzi")`, `@Table(name = "uslugi_mrt")`

Есть ли какая-то возможность использовать один класс для сохранения данных в разные одинаковые таблицы или все же нужно для каждой таблицы свои классы создавать? Просто этот класс используется во многих местах, а если создавать такие классы для каждого отделения будет много дублирующегося кода.

Comment: Если опустить за скобки вопрос о том, не стоит ли все услуги хранить в одной таблице, раз они настолько одинаковые, то можно, по идее, сделать класс `AbstractUslugi` без `Table` и `Entity` аннотаций и от него унаследовать классы типа `UslugiUzi` и `UslugiMrt` уже с аннотациями `Table` и `Entity`. Во всяком случае можно попробовать - кажется, оно будет работать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Hibernate существует три стратегии для маппинга иерархии классов на таблицы, которые можно выбрать при помощи аннотации `@Inheritance`:

- `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`
  Используется по умолчанию, считается наиболее эффективной стратегией с точки зрения производительности, так как в ней нет необходимости объединять таблицы.
  Здесь вся иерархия записывается в одну таблицу, в которую добавляется колонка-дискриминатор при помощи аннотации `@DiscriminatorColumn`, значение которой для каждого класса определяется при помощи аннотации `@DiscriminatorValue`.
  Такая таблица объединяет поля для всех классов-потомков (которые следовательно должны быть Nullable), каждый класс-потомок использует свой набор полей.
- `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`
  Для каждого класса создаётся и поддерживается отдельная таблица со своим полным набором полей.  Атрибуты родительского класса могут переопределяться в классах-потомках при помощи `@AttributeOverrides`.
  Разновидностью этой стратегии можно считать использование абстрактного родительского класса, отмеченного аннотацией `@MappedSuperclass`, тогда родительский класс не будет мапиться на свою конкретную таблицу.
- `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)`
  Таблицы для классов-потомков содержат внешний ключ для связи с таблицей родительского класса `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` и наборы только своих полей.

Comment: Спасибо, поизучаю разновидности и попробую реализовать